# CSS3 Transition Menu Openup

Tags: css

Is it possible to open up child menu element with transition effect from top to bottom ?

Can I make it work with this ?

http://tinyurl.com/7rxskdj

Comment: Based on what HTML? With what CSS? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I tried http://css.dzone.com/articles/create-shiny-and-bright-css3

Comment: As you can see, it works there: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/232/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is my friend;

http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/232/index.html

Download it from here;
http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-multicolor-menu/